# Resize picture in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, image-processing, resize, object-detection

I have to resize my picture for classification project. I used this code, but the code error. can anyone help me. I am really appreciated.
[error message show in this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JtCpQ.png)

```
import skimage
from skimage import io, transform

Image_path = 'C:\banhmi'
coll = skimage.io.ImageCollection(Image_path + '/*.jpg')
for i in range(len(coll)):
    image = skimage.transform.resize(coll[i], [300, 300])
```

Comment: when using for loop in python with CMD environment tab or space requires(it apply autimaticly in SDK). just a tab before `image=skimage.transfrom.resize(coll[i],[300,300])`

Answer (score 0):

You need to indent the foor loop used in your code, the statements inside any loops or if-else conditions must be indented in python.Its a syntax issue.

```
for i in range(len(col1)):
    image = skimage.transform.resize(col1[i], [300,300])
```